# Can a custom hardware interface access parameters on the parameter server other than HardwareInfo?

Tags: ros2, ros2-control, hardware-interface

Can a custom hardware interface access parameters on the parameter server other than HardwareInfo? For example, the parameters in the controller.yaml file? How can I access them?

In ROS1 for example, I can access `root_nh.getParam("controllers_namespace", controllers_namespace))` to get parameter in yaml file. Can ROS2 do it? How?

Comment: please don't copy code as image, because search engines can't find this in the future. You can edit your question and add a code block inside.

Comment: Please paste any code or console output as code formatted text and not as a screenshot. Screenshots are not text searchable, [amongst other things](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)....

Answer (score 2):

The controller.yaml is not forwarded to the hardware components, but you can add parameters to the ros2_control tag inside the URDF. See the [demos](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos/blob/ff8dd8bce5d086fa307a495047d68ac85f4e7523/example_1/hardware/rrbot.cpp#L39-L41) here. You can also parse the full original URDF (`original_xml` field of HardwareInfo struct).

In ROS 2 there is nothing like a parameter server. If you want to parse parameters, you have to add a node to your hardware component. But this is not preferable if you are concerned about realtime capabilities.